# How to add a function call to a list?

Tags: python, list, function, python-2.7

I have a Python code that uses the following functions:

```
def func1(arguments a, b, c):

def func2(arguments d, e, f):

def func3(arguments g, h, i):
```

Each of the above functions configures a CLI command on a product.

In addition, for each of the above functions, there is the de-init function which deletes the CLI command.

```
def de_init_func1(arguments x, y, z):

def de_init_func2(arguments l, m, n):

def de_init_func3(arguments q, r, s):
```

Suppose I have a script which configures lots of CLI commands using the functions func1, func2 and func3, and before the script completes, the script should remove all the CLI commands that it configured.

For this to happen, each time func1/2/3 is invoked, I need to add the equivalent de_init_func CALL to a list, so by the end of the script, I can iterate this list, and invoke the de-init methods one by one.

How can I add a "func1(arguments) call" to a list without invoking it while adding it to the list.

If I will just add the func1(arguments) call as a string "func1(arguments)", once I will iterate the list, I won`t be able to invoke the function calls because interpreter will refer to the list items as strings and not as function calls...

Comment: Do all the functions take the same arguments?

Comment: No. func1, func2 and func3 takes different arguments.

Comment: I guess you can handle that with the `with` statement http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/

Comment: What about the "de_init" functions--same argument for de_init_func1 as for func1 or not?

Comment: I updated the post as per your inputs. Assume each function take different arguments.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At the simplest level, you can simply use tuples for referencing function calls. For example, a call to `func1(a, b, c)` would be  referenced by the tuple `(func1, a, b, c)`. You can then safely put those tuples in a list.

To execute later the function represented by such a tuple (say `t`), simply use :

```
t[0](*t[1:])
```

That is : call the function in t[0] with the arguments in the remaining of typle.

Comment: I used this to create a list of websocket.recv() calls and I forgot putting the : in the call so my statement looked like this: 
`t[0](*t[1])`
that ended up calling the websocket libraries _iter_ function, i am wondering if you could help me out and explain what happened there? Or any reading material in this way of calling functions from a list of tuples would help too. 
[websocket-client](https://pypi.org/project/websocket_client/)

Comment: For clarity's sake, you could unpack `t` first, like `func, *args = t`, then you can do `func(*args)`.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I add a "func1(arguments) call" to a list without invoking it while adding it to the list.

There are at least two ways:

```
def test(x):
    print "arg was "+str(x)
toDoList = []
args = ["hello"]
toDoList.append(lambda:test(*args))
# doesn't run yet
# run it
for f in toDoList:
    f()
```

If you think you might want to inspect or change the args before running, this next one is better:

```
def test(x):
    print "arg was "+str(x)
toDoList = []
args = ["hello"]
toDoList.append({'f': test, 'a': args})
# to run
for item in toDoList:
     item['f'](*item['a'])
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
from functools import partial

L.append(partial(de_init_func1, x, y, z))
L.append(partial(de_init_func2, l, m, n))

for f in L:
    f()
```

This supports kwargs if needed. Also, if there are shared arguments for the functions or some are unknown in the beginning, you can postpone their passing until the final call.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use class ; funcx as contructor (__init__) and de_init_funcx as destructor (__del__).

```
class Class1:
    def __init__( self, arguments, a, b ,c ):
        ...

    def __del__( self, arguments, x, y, z ):
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
setup = [func1, func2, func3]
teardown = [de_init_func1, de_init_func2, de_init_func3]

map(lambda func: func(arguments), setup) # calls all the setup functions
map(lambda func: func(arguments, teardown) # calls all the teardown functions
```