# How to create a list of functions for call in python

Tags: python, list

If I had approximately 10 commands, and they all served specific purposes, so they couldn't be modified, but I wanted to put them in a list without calling them.

```
def print_hello():
    print("hello")

command_list = [print_hello()]
```

This would only print `"hello"`, then leave `command_list` equal to `[None]`

How would I get it so that when I type `command_list[0]`, it would perform `print_hello()`?

My question is like this one here, but I don't understand. [How to add a function call to a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26881396/how-to-add-a-function-call-to-a-list#)

Comment: *"How would I get it so that when I type command_list[0], it would perform print_hello()?"* – Hardly at all. Would `command_list[0]()` do?

Comment: `command_list=[print_hello]`

Comment: To make access by index call the resulting object, you'd have to write your own custom list to make `__getitem__` invoke `__call__`. Or just put the function in the list and call it when you get it back, as @deceze suggests.

Comment: print_hello() is function call while print_hello wo () is function object. You want to store function objects into list therefore you need to append it to list without (). Further you want to make function call upon stored function objects that is why you need to append () after list item command_list[0]()

Comment: Yes, `command_list[0]()` would do perfectly. Sorry for terrible phrasing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to add them to the list without calling them, just refrain from calling them:

```
command_list = [print_hello]
```

At the time you want to call them, call them:

```
command_list[0]()
```

If you want something to happen by just doing `command_list[0]`, you could subclass `list` and give it a

```
def __getitem__(self, index):
    item = list.__getitem__(self, index)
    return item()
```

(untested). Then the item getting operation on the list causes the function to be called.